# 404 Error is not working with /dir/file.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Okay I will post this question in hope that you understand What i am talking about using your skill and knowledge

I have a 404 error file on the root directory, named `error404.html`.
As well, I have a .htaccess File with the line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

If you come on my site https://www.mysite/index.php that works good.

If you try and find a page that is not there, for example https://www.mysite/nothere.php, my error page comes up and works okay.

If you come to my site and go to https://www.mysite/other/apage.php all is okay.
If you try and find a page that is not there https://www.mysite/other/nothere.php my error page comes up and works okay

So here is my problem:

You come to my site and go to https://www.mysite/other/apage.php and this page should work but you made a mistake and actually typed in https://www.mysite/other/apage.php/nothere.php, instead of showing my 404 error, it tries to show
https://www.mysite/other/apage.php with missing text and pictures

Why did I not get the 404 error page?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior of PHP request handler, because `other/apage.php` is a valid file and [AcceptPathInfo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html) directive is set to On by default.

To disable this behavior explicitly:

- In your Apache configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AcceptPathInfo Off
</Directory>
```

- or in your .htaccess file

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Comment: Thank you for your time my .htaccess file now have ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
AcceptPathInfo Off in it but no difference have i missed some thing thanks andy